# May you assist me with the output of this Fibonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47X1a.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: You should at least *attempt* your own homework before dumping it on us.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 1 : 1
n = 2 : 1
n = 3 : Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2) + Fib(n-3) = Fib(2) + Fib(1) + Fib(0) = 1 + 1 + 0 = 2
n = 4 : Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2) + Fib(n-3) = Fib(3) + Fib(2) + Fib(1) = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4
```

Basically, you add the 3 previous number before n.